# how to trigger an onmouseover event on element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, triggers, onmouseover

As titled, how do I trigger an `onmouseover` event on element in javascript? please refer to Code Snippet. Instead of hovering over the big box, can I click on the small black box and execute the `onmouseover` event? The goal is NOT to turn the box blue but TRIGGER the `onmouseover` event. And also I need this to be done with only JavaScript, no Jquery please.

```js
function showBlue() {
 document.getElementById('xyz').style.background = "#425dff"; 
}
function showRed() {
 document.getElementById('xyz').style.background = "#e2e2e2";
}
```

```css
#abc{width: 50px; height: 50px; background: #000000; color:#ffffff; cursor: pointer;}
#xyz{width: 200px; height: 200px; background: #e2e2e2;}
```

```html
<div id="abc"><a>click me</a></div>

</br>

<div id="xyz" onmouseover="showBlue()" onmouseout="showGrey()"></div>
```

I tried this but did not work for me :(

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('abc').addEventListener("click", triggerFunction);

    function triggerFunction() {
        document.getElementById('xyz').mouseover();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I need it to be a pure javascript solution if possible

Comment: I wish I could downvote that comment Teemu :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```js
function showBlue() {
 document.getElementById('xyz').style.background = "#425dff"; 
}
function showGrey() {
 document.getElementById('xyz').style.background = "#e2e2e2";
}
function triggerMouseOver() {
    document.getElementById('xyz').onmouseover();
}
```

```css
#abc{width: 50px; height: 50px; background: #000000; color:#ffffff; cursor: pointer;}
#xyz{width: 200px; height: 200px; background: #e2e2e2;}
```

```html
<div id="abc" onclick="triggerMouseOver()"><a>click me</a></div>

</br>

<div id="xyz" onmouseover="showBlue()" onmouseout="showGrey()"></div>
```

You could also simply do this:

```
<div id="abc" onclick="document.getElementById('xyz').onmouseover()"><a>click me</a></div>
```

Comment: Your element uses `showGrey`, but you've only declared `showBlue` and `showRed`. I think the `showRed` function needs renamed?

Comment: This would work with inline handlers only ...

Comment: Yes, his code had that wrong name but I forgot to fix it. I will update my answer code.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `onmouseover()` instead of `mouseover()`

```
document.getElementById('xyz').onmouseover();
```